# Backbone JS: self populate Collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a Backbone collection like this

```
var ContactsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Contact,

    initialize: function () {
            //retrieves contacts from web service
            //contactsLoaded: is the callback that gets called after 
            //the contacts get received
            loadContacts(this.contactsLoaded);
    },

    contactsLoaded: function (contacts) {
            for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
              //TODO populate the collection [models][1]
            }
    }
});
```

in other word, I want to self populate the collection's [models](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-models),
how can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Backbone collection, you needn't to add the model one by one, the framework will do the job. Simply

```
var ContactsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Contact,
  url: '/contacts' // whatever web service url you are using

  initialize: function () {
    this.fetch();
  }

});
```

If your return from the server is not an JSON array, or it's wrapped with some node, you can override the parse method.

```
parse: function(response) {
  // if it's like {data: [model1, model2, model3...]}
  return response.data
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the REST API as [Collection#fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) should do exactly what you want.

```
var ContactsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: Contact,
url: '', // set the URL
initialize: function () {
  this.fetch();
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're passing in a list of contact models, do this (you don't need a `for` loop):

```
this.add(contacts);
```

[`The docs`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add) mention you can add models one by one, or as an array.

Comment: I did, and received the following error: TypeError:Object doesn't support property or method 'add'. what can be wrong ?

Comment: @MinaSamy check what `this` is assigned to. Also I realized you don't need to add them one by one. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Loamhoof.  You should use backbones fetch to accomplish this.

I suggest you move the call to fetch outside the collections initialize method.  It would be clearer and more handy to put it with the rest of your applications control flow / router logic.  Fetch will return a jqXHR object implements a promise interface.  Allowing you to do something like this:

```
var contactsCollection = new ContactsCollection({});
var p = contactsCollection.fetch();

p.done(function() { ... });
p.error(function() { ... });
p.always(function() { ... });
```